# When to use May be and May have been?

Tags: meaning

Which one is correct to say?

a) He was may be drunk when the incident occurred.

b) He may have been drunk when the incident occurred.

Comment: I believe you want to compare *may have been* with the single word *maybe*.

Answer (score 3):

You say "when the incident ***occurred***." So, the whole sentence should be:

> He **may have been** drunk when the incident occurred.

*May* is a modal verb of possibility, and we can use it to refer to the past using *have + V3* after it.
If we don't use *have + V3*, the modal verb refers either to the present or future. Compare these:

> You may be drunk. (now)
>
> He may/might have been drunk. (in the past)

Note that you can also say:

> **Maybe** he was drunk when the incident occurred.

*Maybe* is **one word** now, and it's no longer a modal verb but an adverb.
The meaning of the sentences is pretty much the same:

> He may have been drunk when the incident occurred.
>
> Maybe he was drunk when the incident occurred.